# Installing a Plug-in into Eclipse from its source code

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, installation

There is a plug-in which can actually be found in its dedicated update site and installed from there into eclipse. But for my project, I need the most up-to-date version of this plug-in which can be found it its source code within the GIT repository. So I have downloaded a clone of the source code from the GIT repository into Eclipse. It all looks right, but in the end I need this source code to be compiled and installed as the plug-in into my Eclipse Development IDE (not in a runtime environment!). What are the next steps I need to follow? I would be very glad, if you could hepl me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing an Eclipse Plugin that you've compiled from Source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207763/installing-an-eclipse-plugin-that-youve-compiled-from-source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question "[Installing an Eclipse Plugin that you've compiled from Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2213125/6309)" mentions two ways:

- use the export wizard: `File/Export`, look for `export Deployable plug-ins and fragments`, select the compiled plug-in, and then in the lower half of the page select **`Install into host repository`**.
- Or export your plug-in into a directory, and then copy the directory into the dropins folder.

Check "[Eclipse plugin developed under Helios doesn't show in Juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876569/eclipse-plugin-developed-under-helios-doesnt-show-in-juno)" if you have troubles to make your plugin visible after installation.
You can test a plugin [with "`Launch an Eclipse application`" under "`Testing`"](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#wizward_launch).

Comment: It seems to work with the Export option. There were also no troubles that Eclipse couldn't see the plug-in. But it seems, that somehow the plug-in from the update site is over-acting on the plug-in I have installed from its source code. Some functions, which should be within the up-to-date plug-in installed from the source code, but not in the one from the update site, aren't simply there. Is really such a conflict possible?

Comment: @DanglingElse it is possible, depending on the order the plugin is loaded. Would it be possible for you to *uninstall* that plugin first, before importing its sources and compiling it?

Comment: I would try it and post the outcome here. Thanks a lot!